# Ruby/Rails with Rails Engine (Redmine plugins) - Adding to a base view without overriding it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, rails-engines

I have a plugin that needs to add something the the base Redmine layout. The change consists of a couple divs and a call to a JavaScript function. Currently I am accomplishing this by simply overriding the base layout view.

I don't like doing this since if we upgrade Redmine any pages overridden would not update with the updated version. Is there a more elegant way to add this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the [Redmine Hooks](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/Hooks) to add content to the base layout.